# resources assert file not found

Tags: c++, audio, plugins, resources

i have a problem with **resources** in my audio plugin

here is my resource file

```
// Unique IDs for each image resource.
#define BCKG_ID 101
#define CANT_ID 102
#define COM10_ID 103
#define COM20_ID 104
#define COM40_ID 105
#define COM80_ID 106
#define SAVE_ID 107
#define WAIT_ID 108
#define ONOFFBYPASS_ID 109
#define ONOFFPRESSED_ID 110

// Image resource locations for this plug.
#define BCKG_FN "resources/img/background.png"
#define CANT_FN "resources/img/cant.png"
#define COM10_FN "resources/img/combo10.png"
#define COM20_FN "resources/img/combo20.png"
#define COM40_FN "resources/img/combo40.png"
#define COM80_FN "resources/img/combo80.png"
#define SAVE_FN "resources/img/savwav.png"
#define WAIT_FN "resources/img/waiting.png"
#define ONOFFBYPASS_FN  "resources/img/onoff-bypass.png"
#define ONOFFPRESSED_FN "resources/img/onoff-pressed.png"
```

i have an **assert** issue : **"file not found"** when using this code :

```
IBitmap onoff1 = pGraphics->LoadIBitmap(ONOFFBYPASS_ID, ONOFFBYPASS_FN, 1);
```

if i use **WAIT_ID** instead of **ONOFFBYPASS_ID**, everything works

in debug assert this code raises a flag:

```
IBitmap IGraphics::LoadIBitmap(int ID, const char* name, int nStates, bool framesAreHoriztonal)
{
  LICE_IBitmap* lb = s_bitmapCache.Find(ID);
  if (!lb)
  {
    lb = OSLoadBitmap(ID, name);
    #ifndef NDEBUG
    bool imgResourceFound = lb;
    #endif
    assert(imgResourceFound); **//imgResourceFound = false**
    s_bitmapCache.Add(lb, ID);
  }
  return IBitmap(lb, lb->getWidth(), lb->getHeight(), nStates, framesAreHoriztonal);
}
```

i tried to :

1. switch ID values (109 <-> 108)
2. change the names
3. check 10 times the paths

but nothing works

it doesn't makes sense, especially because i have 2 other audio plugins with the same part of code that are **working ok**...

sorry can't provide sample code as it would mean installing VST SDK, WDL-OK...so a bit too much i guess.

please help anyway

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh i made a noob error: i forget to add

```
ONOFFBYPASS_ID PNG ONOFFBYPASS_FN
ONOFFPRESSED_ID PNG ONOFFPRESSED_FN
```

to MyProg.rc

now everything works

Jeff